# Generate random colors (RGB)

Tags: python, random, rgb

I just picked up image processing in python this past week at the suggestion of a friend to generate patterns of random colors. I found this piece of script online that generates a wide array of different colors across the RGB spectrum.

```
def random_color():
    levels = range(32,256,32)
    return tuple(random.choice(levels) for _ in range(3))
```

I am simply interesting in appending this script to only generate one of three random colors. Preferably red, green, and blue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here:

```
def random_color():
    rgbl=[255,0,0]
    random.shuffle(rgbl)
    return tuple(rgbl)
```

The result is either red, green or blue. The method is not applicable to other sets of colors though, where you'd have to build a list of all the colors you want to choose from and then use random.choice to pick one at random.

Answer (score 93):

A neat way to generate RGB triplets within the 256 (aka 8-byte) range is

`color = list(np.random.choice(range(256), size=3))`

`color` is now a list of size 3 with values in the range 0-255. You can save it in a list to record if the color has been generated before or no.

Comment: Should be color = list(np.random.random(size=3) * 256)

Comment: Or without `np`: `rand_color = random.choices(range(256), k=3)`

Comment: You could rather use a tuple: `color = tuple(np.random.random(size=3) * 256)`

Comment: `list(np.array)` returns a list a numpy numeric types. `np.array.tolist()` returns a list of **builtin types** (here: int) expected to be compatible with all libraries such as CV2.

Answer (score 64):

You could also use Hex Color Code,

```
Name    Hex Color Code  RGB Color Code
Red     #FF0000         rgb(255, 0, 0)
Maroon  #800000         rgb(128, 0, 0)
Yellow  #FFFF00         rgb(255, 255, 0)
Olive   #808000         rgb(128, 128, 0)
```

For example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

number_of_colors = 8

color = ["#"+''.join([random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for j in range(6)])
             for i in range(number_of_colors)]
print(color)
```

['#C7980A', '#F4651F', '#82D8A7', '#CC3A05', '#575E76', '#156943', '#0BD055', '#ACD338']

Lets try plotting them in a scatter plot

```
for i in range(number_of_colors):
    plt.scatter(random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0,10), c=color[i], s=200)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just choose the random color from the range 000000-FFFFFF. 

For example you could use the following:                    `f"#{random.randrange(0x1000000):06x}"`

Answer (score 9):

Using [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random%20randint#random.randint):

```
from random import randint

r = randint(0, 255)
g = randint(0, 255)
b = randint(0, 255)
rand_color = (r, g, b)
```

You can also use [`random.randrange()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random%20randrange#random.randrange) for less typing.

```
from random import randrange

r = randrange(255)
g = randrange(255)
b = randrange(255)
rand_color = (r, g, b)
```

You can even do this using one line!

```
from random import randrange

rand_color = (randrange(255), randrange(255), randrange(255))
```

Then you can do whatever you want with this color. One thing you can do is you can create a shape in pygame with the random color.

```
from random import randrange
import pygame

rand_color = (randrange(255), randrange(255), randrange(255))

pygame.draw.line(screen, rand_color, (0, 0), (600, 400), 20)
```

Answer (score 7):

The following code generates a random RGB number `(0-255, 0-255, 0-255)`.

```
color = lambda : [random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)]
```

Comment: Hi @Rahul, could you please add some explanation to your answer?

Comment: this simply returns an array of three random numbers between 0 to 255, which a a whole makes up RGB colour spec.

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by other answers this is more correct code that produces integer 0-255 values and appends alpha=255 if you need RGBA:

```
tuple(np.random.randint(256, size=3)) + (255,)
```

If you just need RGB:

```
tuple(np.random.randint(256, size=3))
```

Comment: RGBA values should be within 0-1 range

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want your color to be sampled from the full possible space of 256×256×256 colors -- since colors produced this way may not look "pretty", many of them being too dark or too white -- you may want to sample a color from a colormap.

The package [cmapy](https://pypi.org/project/cmapy/) contains [color maps from Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) (scroll down for showcase), and allows simple random sampling:

```py
import cmapy
import random
rgb_color = cmapy.color('viridis', random.randrange(0, 256), rgb_order=True)
```

You can make the colors more distinct by adding a range step: `random.randrange(0, 256, 10)`.

Answer (score 4):

With custom colours (for example, dark red, dark green and dark blue):

```
import random

COLORS = [(139, 0, 0), 
          (0, 100, 0),
          (0, 0, 139)]

def random_color():
    return random.choice(COLORS)
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking a uniform random variable as the value of RGB may generate a large amount of gray, white, and black, which are often not the colors we want.

The [`cv::applyColorMap`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html#gadf478a5e5ff49d8aa24e726ea6f65d15) can easily generate a random RGB palette, and you can choose a favorite color map from the list [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html#ga9a805d8262bcbe273f16be9ea2055a65)

Example for C++11:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

std::random_device rd;
std::default_random_engine re(rd());

// Generating randomized palette
cv::Mat palette(1, 255, CV_8U);
std::iota(palette.data, palette.data + 255, 0);
std::shuffle(palette.data, palette.data + 255, re);
cv::applyColorMap(palette, palette, cv::COLORMAP_JET);

// ...

// Picking random color from palette and drawing
auto randColor = palette.at<cv::Vec3b>(i % palette.cols);
cv::rectangle(img, cv::Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), randColor, -1);
```

Example for Python3:

```
import numpy as np, cv2

palette = np.arange(0, 256, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(1, 256, 1)
palette = cv2.applyColorMap(palette, cv2.COLORMAP_JET).squeeze(0)
np.random.shuffle(palette)
# ...

rand_color = tuple(palette[i % palette.shape[0]].tolist())
cv2.rectangle(img, (0, 0), (100, 100), rand_color, -1)
```

If you don't need so many colors, you can just cut the palette to the desired length.

Answer (score 2):

Below solution is without any external package

```py
import random

def pyRandColor():
    randNums = [random.random() for _ in range(0, 3)]

    RGB255 = list([ int(i * 255) for i in randNums ])
    RGB1 = list([ round(i, 2) for i in randNums ])
    return RGB1
```

Example use-case:

```py
print(pyRandColor())
# Output: [0.53, 0.57, 0.97]
```

Note:

- `RGB255` returns list of 3 integers between 0 and 255
- `RGB1` return list of 3 decimals between 0 & 1

Answer (score 1):

Output in the form of (r,b,g) its look like (255,155,100)

```
from numpy import random
color = (random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%x` operator coupled with `randint` here to generate colors

```py
colors_ = lambda n: list(map(lambda i: "#" + "%06x" % random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF),range(n)))
```

Run the function to generate 2 random colors:

```py
colors_(2)
```

Output
['#883116', '#032a54']

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
rgb_full=(random.randint(1,255), random.randint(1,255), random.randint(1,255))
```

Comment: You posted this as an answer. The author's username is added below each answer by default(unless it's a community wiki). Stating that this is an answer and that it is yours is redundant. Instead, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: In any case, random.randint(a,b) samples from the closed interval [a,b] i.e. both ends inclusive, so random.randint(1,256) is incorrect.

Comment: Why are you constructing a string representation of a tuple instead of an actual tuple?

Comment: (edited) at the time of writing i didn't know tuples existed ( i know this sounds stupid lol )

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
import numpy as np

R=np.array(list(range(255))
G=np.array(list(range(255))
B=np.array(list(range(255))
np.random.shuffle(R)
np.random.shuffle(G)
np.random.shuffle(B)
def get_color():

    for i in range(255):
         yield (R[i],G[i],B[i])
palette=get_color()
random_color=next(palette) # you can run this line 255 times
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that you have a data frame, or any array you could generate random colors or sequential colors as follow bellow.

For random colors (you could choose each random colors you will generate):

```
arraySize = len(df.month)
colors = ['', ] * arraySize
color = ["red", "blue", "green", "gray", "purple", "orange"]
for n in range(arraySize):
    colors[n] = cor[random.randint(0, 5)]
```

For sequential colors:

```
import random    
arraySize = len(df.month)
colors = ['', ] * arraySize
color = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange"]
i = 0
for n in range(arraySize):
    if (i >= len(color)):
        i = 0
    colors[n] = color[i]
    i = i+1
```

Answer (score -3):

```
    from random import randint,choice
    from PIL import ImageColor
    #random choice colorlist
    colorlist = ["#23a9dd","#BE6E46","#CDE7B0","#A3BFA8"]
    #random r g b select
    r = randint(0, 255)
    g = randint(0, 255)
    b = randint(0, 255)
    #random choice selector
    qcl = choice(RandomColorButton.colorlist)
    rand_color = (r, g, b)
    #random choice selected convert in RGB int
    print(ImageColor.getcolor(qcl, "RGB"))
    print(rand_color)
```