# How to use RGB color model in Python

Tags: python-2.7, colors, rgb, textcolor, text-coloring

I want to pick a random color using RGB in Python. The problem is that I don't know how to write RGB color model's syntax; besides, I also don't know which library should I call to accomplish that.

Comment: possible duplicate [Generate random colors (RGB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999287/generate-random-colors-rgb) ?

Comment: you can try opencv

Answer (score 0):

Try the `colorsys` library, used often with `PyGame` and other graphical libraries to convert colors between RGB and other coordinate systems. Here is a link to learn more: https://docs.python.org/3/library/colorsys.html

Comment: Actually, and to be clearer, I was using Turtle library.
I solved it; and this is how I used RGB random color in my code:
'#R = random.random()
#G = random.random()
#B = random.random()
#turtle.color((R, G, B))