# how to change the color in grabcut mask based on a class

Tags: python, opencv

here's my image:

[image]

i have 2 classes dog and truck i also have their bbox coordinates so i want to create a mask for this image so i applied grapcut algorithm here's my code

```
img=cv2.imread('dog.jpg')
mask=np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)

bgModel=np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgModel=np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
tmpimage=image
masks=[]
for i in recs:
    cv2.grabCut(img,mask,i,bgModel,fgModel,10,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
    mask2=np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
    masks.append(mask2)
    #img=image*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]
finalmask=np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)
for i in range(len(masks)):
   finalmask=finalmask+masks[i]
plt.imshow(finalmask)
# plt.colorbar()
#plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

here's the final mask:

[image]

what i want to do is i want the area of the dog to have different color than area of the truck in this image both are having the same yellow color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `finalmask` is a 2-channel image. The output you get from `plt.imshow(finalmask)` is a binary image where yellow -> 255 and purple -> 0.

I have created a mask with 3-channels and assigned random colors for each mask.

**Code:**

```
# creating 3-channel mask:
finalmask = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8)

for i in range(len(masks)):
    # generating random color 
    # plucked from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999287/generate-random-colors-rgb
    color = tuple(np.random.choice(range(256), size=3))

    # create another mask to place color in white regions
    im = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8)
    im[masks[i] == 255] = color

    # add with final mask
    finalmask = finalmask + im
```

**Results:**

Here sample masks I created:

[image]  &  [image]

End result:

[image]

> ***Note:*** If you want fixed color for each mask label, you can create a dictionary and refer from it.

Comment: when i try to display the mask it only gives me black picture

Comment: i solved it in my case the white area was equals to 1 not 255 that was the problem but thank u btw this answer really helped me